# Custom NotifyIcon ballon in VS2005

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, notifyicon

I want to show the notifyicon's balloon in custom shape (i.e) **Rectangle** with color controls i like.how to do this i am using VS2005 how to achieve this.

Suggestions of 3rd-party tools are fine.

Comment: What language/library? C++/C#? MFC/WinForms/Qt?